# How to add a value of -1/2 on the amplitude of a quantum state?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, programming

I have a quantum state which is in

$ \cos(c*f(x) + \pi/4) |0\rangle + \sin(c*f(x) + \pi/4) |1\rangle$

by using bunch of RY gates. Now I want to measure the probability of getting the state at $|1\rangle$ , that I know will be:

$ \sin^2(c*f(x) + \pi/4)$

but instead I want this state to be:

$ \sin^2(c*f(x) + \pi/4) - 1/2$

What gate operation will add this to the amplitude of my quantum state?

Comment: Do you know the value of $c*f(x)$?

Comment: Yes, so c = 0.01 and f(x) is a function like 2x + 4 where x ranges from 0 to 7

Comment: Do you want to apply a single gate that'll work for any $x$ or do you know $x$ and you only need a gate that'll work for a given $x$?